# Is the relation $\sim$ an equivalence relation, where $(x_1,y_1)\sim(x_2,y_2)$ means that $(x_1, y_1)=(\lambda x_1,\lambda y_1)$ for some $\lambda$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-explanation, relations, equivalence-relations

> Define a relation on $\mathbb R^2 \setminus (0, 0)$ by letting
> $(x_1, y_1) \sim (x_2, y_2)$ mean that there exists a nonzero real number $\lambda$ such that
> $(x_1, y_1) = (λx_2, λy_2)$.
>
> Prove that $\sim$ defines an equivalence relation
> on $\mathbb R^2 \setminus (0, 0)$. What are the corresponding equivalence classes and show its geometric interpretation?
>
> Also we define the operation $[(x_1,y_1)]*[(x_2,y_2)]=[(x_1x_2-y_1y_2, x_1y_2+x_2y_1)]$, prove this is a valid definition.

I was able to prove it is an equivalence relation, however I don't know the equivalence classes (shouldn't it just be a line that goes through the centre $(0,0)$? Also how would you geometrically present this line? Or maybe i have a hole in my knowledge.  I'm completely lost on the 3rd question.

Comment: As an observation, the quotient space here is well-known as the *projective real line* $\mathbb{R} \mathbb{P}^1$; and you might see the notation of *homogeneous coordinates* where $[x : y]$ is notation for the equivalence class of $(x, y)$.  You can think of $\mathbb{R} \mathbb{P}^1$ as $\mathbb{R}$ plus a "point at infinity", where the copy of $\mathbb{R}$ is the points of the form $[t : 1]$ for $t \in \mathbb{R}$, and then the point at infinity is $[1 : 0]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct: two points are equivalent if and only if they lie along the same line.
To show that the multiplication is "valid" you need to show that it is well-defined, i.e. that the result does not depend on your choice of representative of the equivalence class. Namely, if  $(x_1, y_1)= \lambda_1 (x_2,y_2)$ and $(x_3,y_3)=\lambda_2 (x_4,y_4)$,
(i.e. take different representatives of the each equivalence class), you need to check that $$[x_1,y_1]*[x_3,y_3]=[x_2,y_2]*[x_4,y_4]$$ so that the product does not depend on your choice of representative for each equivalence class.
For this, you will need to check that two sides of the equation are scalar multiples of each other, which will mean they represent the same equivalence class.

Comment: Yup, great point, I'll change that

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but how would i concretely write down the answer for that geometric interpretation? as in all lines that go rhough the origin?

Comment: and for the 3rd question, you basically wrote down the answer right?   Sorry just started university i dont really know how to do these kind of things...

Comment: Hi, yes, you would say that two points of are equivalent if they lie on the same line through the origin. The set of all such equivalence classes can then be thought of as the set of all lines through the origin.

Comment: And no, there is still work to do for the third question. Explicitly compute the left and right hand sides using the multiplication rule, and show that one is a scalar multiple of the other.

Comment: If the answer is helpful, would you consider upvoting?

Comment: i already upvoted...sorry one more follow up question and this sounds really stupid...You mean i should just multiply both sides by λ1 and λ2? but how do i prove that its just a scalar multiple of the other? because its proven before thats it is an equivalence relation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130096/discussion-between-mwalth-and-jerry-cohen).